# What is the power generating capacity for an airport GPU?

Tags: airport, ground-operations, electrical-system

What is the normal current for GPU power supply for commercial aircraft and how much power do they need while on ground (in kWh)?

I have read that aircraft need need 28V DC and 115V AC - what would be the percentage between both modes of supply?

Would it by possible to power GPUs entirely by solar power?

Comment: You mentioned commercial aircraft but tagged this with general aviation. Are there specific aircraft types you are interested in? The power requirements will depend on aircraft size and type.

Comment: `kWh` is a measure of energy, not power. Energy is power applied over time.

Comment: @andrewmh20 Nope, you're backwards. [See here](http://www.ccontrolsys.com/w/Energy_(kWh)_vs._Power_(kW)) for example.

Comment: @andrewmh20 `Wh` is `watts` multiplied by `time`. Power has the time component divided out.

Comment: @andrewmh20 I'm a software engineer at a company that produces watt-hour standards - I'm pretty sure I'm correct. Anyway, this is off-topic and we've discussed it enough. Believe what you will.

Comment: @andrewmh20 One last comment - I think *you're* misinterpreting "applied over time". In this case, "over" does *not* mean division. It means multiplication. Power is integrated over time, and the area under the curve, if you were to plot it, is the energy. One dimension is power, one dimension is time. The area is `power * time`, also known as `energy`. And I never mentioned arguing..

Answer (score 2):

Power requirements are dependent on airframe and configuration ([see this question for a general idea](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/how-much-electrical-power-is-available-in-a-gulfstream-g550-and-from-which-power)). GPU's come in varying sizes for varying aircraft types. [For example this GPU](http://www.aerospecialties.com/aviation-ground-support-equipment-gse-products/tld-ground-support-equipment/tld-gpu-406-e-cup-28-60-kva-ac-28v-dc-diesel-ground-power-unit/) (arbitrarily chosen) can deliver: *800 amps continuous, 2500 amps peak.* [While this GPU](http://www.sportys.com/pilotshop/70-amp-aircraft-ground-power-unit-gpu-with-batteryminder.html) can only drive 70Amps continuous. Others may be able to drive more and some may drive [less](http://www.sportys.com/pilotshop/35-amp-aircraft-ground-power-unit-gpu.html). Are you asking about a particular application? The GPU's at the tiny airport I fly out of that we use to bump start the occasional Piper are no where near the capacity of what you may find at JFK for starting up a 747.

> Would it by possible to power GPUs entirely by solar power?

Depends on the application but it would be unlikely to chose such a medium for powering a GPU the way things stand now (in terms of power requirements). You may be able to have a battery powered GPU that is charged by solar cells but that would only work well in the smaller scenario. Having a solar powered airport that can provide ground power is a whole different question.

Comment: An accepted energy density for the raw solar power on the Earth is 1.3 kW/m² at noon with no clouds. [Cells are about 25% efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell_efficiency#/media/File:PVeff(rev160420).jpg) for conversion into current (higher efficiency cells exist only in labs at the moment).